# How many "Periscope" users are online in the same real time and watching streams?

Tags: mobile, stream

Question is about Periscope app.  How many "Periscope" users are online and  watching streams at the same time?

Answer (score -1):

- There was a total of 10 million active monthly users in August 2015
- The daily average of users is 1.85 million

Comment: Thanks, but question was about real time users online in one moment, not per day.